# How do I combine StoreKit with Promo Codes for In-App Purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, promotion-code

My app uses [StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit) to handle in-app purchases. Now I would like to make use of the recently introduced [promotional codes feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html). The documentation explains how to generate and redeem codes. However, I have no clue in which way a redeemed promo code would be reflected inside my app (somehow, the user should be notified about the product that (s)he gets for free).

Currently, the app generates `SKProductRequest`s and receives `SKProductReponse`s to get the prices, titles and further information for each product:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response;
{
    NSNumber* price1 = [response.products objectAtIndex:0].price;
    ...
}
```

Now I would either expect the price for an already redeemed product to be `0` which is currently not the case. Alternatively, I would suppose that there is some API which tells me whether a user actually needs to pay for a single instance of a product.

Comment: Did you discover any solution to this?

Comment: @Cory Unfortunately, I have not :(.